# Why query response time is more in node.js or express.js compare to PHP and Mysql Client?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous, npm

I'm comparing response/execution time of query with PHP script and express.js (mysql npm module) and mysql (command line).

I observed that response time is more in node.js compare to others.

My query :

```
     SELECT (1 + 1) AS result
```

**Response time (avg)**

- Express js : 2 ms
- Mysql (command-line) : less than 0 ms
- PHP Script : 0.11 ms

**code in Express JS**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mysql = require('mysql');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "test"
    });

    global.start = Date.now();

    connection.query('SELECT (1 + 1) AS result', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        connection.end();
        let end = Date.now();
        let elapsed = end - global.start;
        let result = results[0]['result'];
        res.send('Result : ' + result + ' <br/> Time Elapsed : ' + elapsed + ' ms');
    });    
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**Code in PHP**

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'test';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT 1 + 1 AS result";

$start = microtime(true);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$end = microtime(true);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Result: " . $row["result"] . "<br>";
        echo 'Time Elapsed : ' . number_format(($end-$start)*1000,2) . ' ms <br/>';
            }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}



$conn->close();
?>
```

I expect response time of node.js (mysql npm module) should be approximately matched with others.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow. You may want to rewrite the question to make the question more obvious.

Comment: I agree. One way to ask this might be "Why is there an additional 12ms" of response time when querying through Express.JS.  You will most likely get an answer to the effect that you are not actually comparing MySQL Sequel Pro to Node.JS here, but rather you are comparing Sequel Pro to Express.JS, which is not a good comparison because the express app is querying over HTTP and therefore it adds the overhead of the HTTP connection setup and network transfer.  If you were to query the database from node directly instead of going through Express, I expect you would find the response times similar.

Comment: @Darren, Thanks for your reply. I have used express.js (node.js framework) to host API on port 8080 and used npm "mysql" module. Right now I'm connecting with localhost and comparing with PHP, mysql client (command line). Still there is significant difference in response time. Please check edited description.

Comment: One difference that's immediately noticeable is that you're invoking a call to close the database connection before calculating the duration and sending the result to the user, in the Express version.  I'm not sure how much overhead closing the database connection introduces, but you may want to modify it to execute the same flow as the PHP version so that your comparison is more accurate.

Comment: @Darren, I moved db connection closing line to end of callback function but still facing same issue. According to my observation node.js itself takes time to call the callback function after execution of query.

Comment: Likely you are not actually getting full results from the `$conn->query($sql)` statement in PHP.  A query response time of 0.11ms does not seem at all realistic. Further down, you're calling `$result->fetch_assoc()` after the `start` and `end` times are already set (0.11 ms apart). Set the end time after the `$row` has been read from the database.